# Is this sufficient to show $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^{b_n}f(x)dx=\int_a^bf(x)dx$?

Tags: analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be an Riemann integrable function and let ${b_n}$ be a sequence in $[a,b]$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=b.$$
Show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^{b_n}f(x)dx=\int_a^bf(x)dx.$$

Attempt at solution:$$\begin{equation}\begin{split}\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^{b_n}f(x)dx & =\lim_{\|P\|\to0}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{m}f(\xi_k)\Delta x_k\\ & =\lim_{\|P\|\to0}\left (\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}f(\xi_k)\Delta x_k +\lim_{n\to\infty}f(\xi_m)(b_n-x_{m-1}) \right ) \\ & = \lim_{\|P\|\to0}\left (\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}f(\xi_k)\Delta x_k +f(\xi_m)(b-x_{m-1}) \right ) \\ & = \int_a^bf(x)dx.
\end{split}\end{equation}$$
It seems a bit simple. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You exchanged two limit processes. The partition you select depends on the left endpoint, so that the sample points $\xi_k$ ultimately depend on $n$. You pass to a limit in $n$ without acknowledging that dependence.

Comment: Would that mean this method of proof is completely unworkable or is there something else I could try?

Comment: It will be difficult  using limits. Instead I would suggest using an $\epsilon$ argument, as in for each $\epsilon$ there exists a partition $P$ satisfying...

Comment: No explicit reference to partitions is required; you only need to bound $\int_{b_n}^b f(x) dx$, which is easy because Riemann integrable functions are bounded by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\int_a^b f - \int_a^{b_n} f = \int_{b_n}^b f .$

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a really useful answer: The question is whether the OP's work is sufficient to prove the claim, which is not at all addressed by a one-line hint that goes in a different direction.

Comment: It's certainly useful; there's more to some problems than the original specific question

Comment: I see the MSE vigilantes are out. Who gave me the down vote?